# Is the idea that there is always at least one illness with an unknown cure - a Jewish idea?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, sources-mekorot, medicine, choleh-sick

I have heard many times that there will always be at least one illness that is uncurable. Is this a Jewish idea? What is its source?

Comment: This is not an answer, which is why I'm not posting it as such, but there's a story (the veracity of which I can in no way vouch for) that the _Chazon Ish_ claimed that he could cure cancer (presumably through his genius, by discovering the cure, though I've seen some interpret it as meaning that he could divine the cure through _ruach hakodesh_; in any event) but he did not do so because God would simply send along another illness as bad. This story is mentioned (in one of its variants) at http://parsha.blogspot.com/2009/07/did-chazon-ish-violate-did-chazal.html for example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking no because in Sefer Nishmat Avraham- Orach Chaim Siman 1 it is written: "Indeed, Chazal stated: The Holy One, Blessed be He, said: There is no illness for which a complete cure is not already present.

The footnote says(I'm translating from Hebrew) [Tanchumah Yitro Chet](http://www.tsel.org/torah/tanhuma/yitro.html)